# Probability distribution of random variables

Tags: probability, distributions

The SAT is used as an aid in determining college admissions. This test is a multiple choice test. To discourage random guessing, points are subtracted for wrong answers. Each question has 5 possible answers, and the test taker must pick one answer or choose not to answer the question. One point is awarded for each correct answer, and for each wrong answer 1/4 point is subtracted. Construct a table of probability distribution of the random variable x, which represents the point for each answer. Then calculate the expected point value of a random guess.

Comment: I think you need the self-study tag.

Answer (score 1):

So, If I understand correctly, you are asking for the probability distribution of the number of points for a *single question.*

The use of a Bernoulli (0 or 1) random variable can help here. Let $Y \sim Bern(p)$, where $p$ is the probability of getting a question correct. Then the number of points earned or lost on a single question is:
\begin{equation}
X = Y - \frac{1}{4}(1-Y)
\end{equation}

So in order to answer your question, first figure out what $p$ is in the case where we are just guessing. Then you must calculate the expected value of $X$. It's a linear function of $Y$, and $\mathbb{E}(Y) = p$.